# Why "appropriate to" should be used in this sentence?

Tags: phrase-usage, sentence-structure, exam-questions

Which of the below answers completes the text so that it conforms to the conventions of standard English?

> The decorations of the rest of the room were noble and yet ________ the destination; garlands, entwined with ivy and vine branches, divided the walls into compartments bordered with fanciful ornaments.

A) owing to
B) appropriate to
C) surprising for
D) foreign to

I'd thought it would be  C. It seemed to me that "and yet" indicates an element of surprise that the decorations are noble (i.e., of high quality), and at the same time not what one would expect. It turned out the right answer is B, but I don't really see how I was supposed to figure it out relying only on this fragment. Would anyone be able to explain it?

Comment: We don't do tests here. Please read the Help section, upper right corner of the screen under thE last icon on the right. There is no way to tell and that question is therefore stupid. [The question, not you]

Comment: As with many of these questions you can't tell.  The general tone of the piece seems to be positive, so "surprising" (which implies criticism) might be out of place.  But not impossible.  There are so many such questions that all you can do is move on. There is nothing much to learn from this.  But please do ask your teacher, They may have some insight into the question